# How to change the name of a network drive with C# - Windows 8 - 10?

Tags: c#, windows, operating-system

I´m able to change the name of a network drive with the following two lines of code:

```
Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
((Shell32.Folder2)shell.NameSpace("K:")).Self.Name = "Drive name";
```

But that doesn't work on `Windows 8` and above. I searched some hours now, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) along with `WMI`. Also make sure you are running this code with elevated privileges.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher disks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume WHERE DriveLetter = 'K:'");
foreach (ManagementObject disk in disks.Get())
{
    disk.Get();
    disk["Label"] = "Drive Name";
    disk.Put();
}
```

**Edit :**
In order to access network drives. Change `root\\CIMV2` to `\\10.180.82.4\root\cimv2` or `\\MachineName\root\cimv2`

Comment: Does this work with network drives? He doesnt find anything.

Comment: Tanks. Do I have to use the host only or the full path to the share like \\192.168.1.111\Sharedfolder\root\cimv2 ?

Comment: This should be enough `\\192.168.1.111\root\cimv2`

Comment: Not working so far. Getting the ErrorCode = -2147023174. The RPC Server is not available.

Comment: See what did I mention in my answer is that you need to have elevated privileges.